# Can't manage to POST image in multipart-form

Tags: java, android, retrofit, mashape, cloudsight

I'm trying to use camfind for an Android app, and using retrofit for all the requests and so. I'm finding huge difficulties uploading my image file to the server using multipart form-data. Can you solve this?

My code:

```
public class getCamFind {
//Set constants
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String API_URL = "https://camfind.p.mashape.com";

//creates object getCamFind, sends request and gets answer
static void getCamResult(String path) throws IOException {

    File imageFile = new File(path); //THIS FILE EXISTS AND SD IS MOUNTED


    String language = new String("en_US");
    String keyMashape = "XXX";


    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            //.setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
            .build();



    // Create an instance of our API interface.
    CamFind camFind = restAdapter.create(CamFind.class);

    camFind.send(keyMashape, language, new TypedFile("image/jpeg", imageFile), new Callback<resultClass>() {
        @Override
        public void success(resultClass result, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus());
            Log.d(TAG, response.getBody().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + retrofitError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

static class Contributor {
    String login;
    int contributions;
}


//interface of the object getCamFind
interface CamFind {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/image_requests")

    void send(
            @Header("X-Mashape-Key") String keyMashape,
            @Part("image_request[locale]") String language,
            @Part("image_request[image]") TypedFile imageFile,

            //@Field("image_request[remote_image_url]") String URL,
            Callback<resultClass> callback);

}

private class resultClass{
    String name;
    String status;

    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    public String getStatus(){return this.status;}


}


}
```

When I send it this way it says `"{"error": {"image": ["invalid image format"]}}"` and when I send it using File instead of typed file, it says `"image": ["can't be blank"]`.

This might be useful, it's the retrofit Log of my POST using cloudsight (basically same exact thing as using mashape, the request is identical) :

```
        06-29 16:59:43.866    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP POST https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests
    06-29 16:59:43.866    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ Authorization: CloudSight XXX
    06-29 16:59:43.866    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ac3731a5-466f-4baf-87d1-b21fddc41701
    06-29 16:59:43.866    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 531
    06-29 16:59:43.879    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ --ac3731a5-466f-4baf-87d1-b21fddc41701
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_request[locale]"
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 5
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    en_US
    --ac3731a5-466f-4baf-87d1-b21fddc41701
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_request[image]"; filename="JPEG_20150627_231626_1086927409.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    --ac3731a5-466f-4baf-87d1-b21fddc41701--
    06-29 16:59:43.880    2483-2502/bookshotco.bookshot2 D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (531-byte body)
```

This might also be useful (look the "image_requests" part) : http://cloudsight.readme.io/v1.0/docs/testinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation of retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedFile.html), the first parameter of the constructor isn't the path of the file.

```
TypedFile(String mimeType, File file)
Constructs a new typed file.
```

It is the mimetype. Try

```
new TypedFile("image/png", imageFile)
```

or

```
new TypedFile("image/jpeg", imageFile)
```

Comment: Well that was a stupid mistake, thanks for that ! Tried again and it still doesn't work though (same exact error)

Comment: Can you try "application/octet-stream" as mimetype?

Comment: In the logfiles you posted, it sais Content-Length: 0. Does the jpeg file have any bytes? Can you log file.length() to assure that?

Comment: I thought it was an upload problem but you seem to be right, the file length is zero. Damn it. Thank you, I'll figure out what's wrong now.

Comment: It works !! Thank you ! Can't believe I made such a beginner's mistake lol

Comment: Don't worry! This happens to everyone :)